# Store objects in ArrayList and output Object description

Tags: java

I am writing a program with separate files in the same package. What I want to do is to use in my Main.java file :

1-Use the values entered by the user create three Triangle objects and stores them in an ArrayList.

2-Display the string representation of each Triangle object in the ArrayList, by calling its toString( ) method and its getArea() method. See the output example below.

- I want all the ouput to display after all the inputs. What I mean is that I want the description of each triangle object to be displayed at the end

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*******************************************************************");
        System.out.println("*   This program gets input for three triangles from the user.    *\n" + "*   It then creates three Triangle objects and displays the       *\n" + "*   description of each..                                         *");
        System.out.println("*******************************************************************");
        System.out.println(); // for adding blank line
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        Triangle triangle; //Define the triangle object
        ArrayList < GeometricObject > list = new java.util.ArrayList < >();;

        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the color of a triangle" + i + "(e.g. \"red\"): ");
            String color = input.next();

            System.out.print("Is the triangle filled (y or n): ");
            boolean filled;
            String filledString = input.next();
            filled = filledString.equals("y"); // condition returns true if "y" is entered
            // User input for triangle's 3 sides
            System.out.println("Enter the lengths of the three sides of the triangle: ");
            double side1 = input.nextDouble();
            double side2 = input.nextDouble();
            double side3 = input.nextDouble();

            // we need to create the triangle object with the input
            triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
            triangle.setColor(color); // calls setColor from GeometricObject
            triangle.setFull(filled); // calls setFilled as well

            // Display the triangle, very similar to TestCircleRectangle.java example
            System.out.println(); // for adding blank line
            System.out.println("Triangle: side1 = " + side1 + "," + " side2 = " + side2 + "," + " side3 = " + side3);
            System.out.println(triangle.toString());

            System.out.printf("Area = %.2f\n", triangle.getArea());
            System.out.println(); // for adding blank line
        }

        System.out.println("Goodbye...");

    }
}
```

**Triangle.java**

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    // Contains 3 double data fields value to 0
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    /** Default constructor that creates a triangle
  *  with default side  of 1.0 each
  *  */
    Triangle() {
        side1 = 1.0;
        side2 = 1.0;
        side3 = 1.0;
    }
    /** parameterized constructor that creates
  * a triangle with sides values
  * */
    Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    /** Getter for side1 */
    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }
    /** Setter for side1 */
    public void setSide1(double newSide1) {
        side1 = newSide1;
    }

    /** Getter for side2 */
    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }
    /** Setter for side2 */
    public void setSide2(double newSide2) {
        side2 = newSide2;
    }

    /** Getter for side3 */
    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }
    /** Setter for side3 */
    public void setSide3(double newSide3) {
        side3 = newSide3;
    }

    /**
  * The getArea Method
  * Purpose: Computes the area of a triangle from 3 sides
  * @return the area of a triangle
  */
    public double getArea() {
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
        return Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
    }
}
```

**GeometricObject.java**

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    /** Construct a default geometric object */
    public GeometricObject() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    /** Construct a geometric object with the specified color
  * and filled value */
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
        this.dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    /** Return color */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /** Set a new color */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean,
  its getter method is named isFilled
  */
    public boolean Full() {
        return filled;
    }

    /** Set a new filled */
    public void setFull(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /** Get dateCreated */
    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    /**
  * Abstract method  getArea
  */

    /** Return a string representation of this object */
    public String toString() {

        return "created on " + getDateCreated() + "\ncolor: " + color + " and filled: " + filled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay? What is stopping you from doing that? What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is more in the Main file. I need to  Prompt the user to enter the values for the sides, color, and filled attribute for three different triangle objects and the objects need to be stored in arrayList

Comment: Yes you said that in your post already. I am asking what your question is, what are you having a problem with.

Comment: Sorry but this is the question " how to Prompt the user to enter the values for the sides, color, and filled attribute for three different triangle objects and the objects  to be stored in ArrayList"

Comment: Here is the Instruction, maybe you will understand me well.

Answer (score 1):

(This should probably be more of a comment than an answer, but I am not sufficiently well known in these parts to comment.  I am working on that!).

As NotZack said, you haven't actually told us what the problem is.  For example, showing us the program's current output compared to what you are aiming for (literally, write down what you want the program to print) would help us know where to start looking.

However, I did notice a few things from quickly looking through your code:

1. you declare an ArrayList in the main file, but I don't see it being used anywhere.  What was the intention of this item?
2. take a deep, deep look at the following line from main:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
```

Get yourself a pen and piece of paper, and write down each value of i in turn which this loop will deal with, bearing in mind the starting value and strictly less than condition.  Is this what you want it to do?

Hopefully that gives you something to start working with :)

Comment: I wanted to use a loop to an ArrayList that will store 3 Triangle objects

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the `triangle` object to list. And move all the code related to printing `triangle` move outside the for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the color of a triangle" + i + "(e.g. \"red\"): ");
        String color = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Is the triangle filled (y or n): ");
        boolean filled = scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y");

        System.out.println("Enter the lengths of the three sides of the triangle: ");
        double side1 = scan.nextDouble();
        double side2 = scan.nextDouble();
        double side3 = scan.nextDouble();

        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
        list.add(triangle);
    }

    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    //Equivalent for above line
    /*for(GeometricObject shape: list){
        System.out.println(shape);
    }*/

}
```

And also add the `toString()` method in `Triangle` class

> You don't need to call the `toString()` method explicitly when you try to print the object it will automatically call the `toString()` method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Triangle: " +
            "side1=" + side1 +
            ", side2=" + side2 +
            ", side3=" + side3 +
            ", Area=" + getArea() +
            "\n" + super.toString();
}
```